# OCaml- Image (.png) to color array

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to load a png image in OCaml and make it into a matrix of color pixels. I'm using the OCaml Graphics module. I think I need to use the CamlImages module as well but I'm not quite sure how to.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's make it clear. The OCaml graphics library doesn't provide any image decoders, so you have to use some other library to decode a file into the representation that the Graphics library understands, which is a matrix of colors.

I failed to find an online documentation for CamlImages, so I will teach you how to generate one using `odig` - the tool for querying and exporing OCaml universe. First of all you need to install it and `odoc` - a documentation generator, e.g., if you're using opam then do

```
opam install odig odoc
```

Now you can do

```
odig doc camlimages
```

and it will generate documentation and open it in your browser.

There you will find the `Png.load` function that will load a file encoded in the PNG format. It will return the image in the one of the CamlImages formats and you have to write a translation function from that format to the matrix of colors format.

Note, if in your course setup you doesn't have opam or odig or odoc, then ask your teachers for documentation. If they are nonresponsive, then you can read the `mli` files directly, the following command will show you all the interfaces available in the CamlImages library:

```
ls $(ocamlfind -query camlimages)/*/*.mli
```